# WCF configuration with https

Tags: wcf, configuration, https

I'm not having any success setting up HTTPS in my development environment on an existing WCF service. The service has been fine with http. I'm using the hosts file to redirect to localhost, which has been working for http.

My web service configuration

```
<services>
  <service name="EnfieldWebService">
    <endpoint address="https://enfieldwebservice.devserver.int/EnfieldWebService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="transportSecurity" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="transportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Client configuration

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEnfieldWebService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://enfieldwebservice.devserver.int/EnfieldWebService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEnfieldWebService"
            contract="HttpsEnfieldService.IEnfieldWebService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IEnfieldWebService" />
    </client>
```

And Unit Test Results:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at
>   https://enfieldwebservice.devserver.int/EnfieldWebService.svc that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404)
>   Not Found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used WCF Configuration Editor to rewrite essentially the same configuration. All that it removed was

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Turns out this feature is only compatible with http, and breaks https.

Comment: What if you have multiple services listed?